# Stripping commas and non-numeric characters from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

should be simple but RegExs never seem to be :). Can anyone help on how to strip both a comma and any non-numeric characters from a string? Thanks. It's in the `var result` block. Apparently when you put an operator in the number it bombs out.`num1` and `num2`. I also need to strip out any dashes.

```
 function calcTotalRetailVal() {
    var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
    var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
   //In the replace method
    var result = parseFloat(num1.replace(/,/g, '')) + parseFloat(num2.replace(/,/g, ''));
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        $totalRetailAmountField.text('$' + result.toFixed(2));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this regex `/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g` to detect comma and any non-numeric value such as characters, operators, spaces in the groups and faster than the individual detection. a negative number (ex -1) and . will be included.

I rewrite your code.

```
function calcTotalRetailVal() {
    var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
    var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
   //In the replace method
    var result = parseFloat(num1.replace(/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g, '')) + parseFloat(num2.replace(/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g, ''));
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        $totalRetailAmountField.text('$' + result.toFixed(2));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const clearText = plainText.replace(/\D/g,'')
```

\D will match all non-digits, but if you need to preserve dots and dashes:

```
replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')
```

Comment: This will also remove a minute sign, which is needed for negative numbers, and the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you, i also need to strip the dash b/c of the case of someone putting in a negative amount.

Comment: replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') then

Comment: I also need to remove commas (sorry to keep bothering)

Comment: replace(/[^\d,-]/g, '') this Will strip dashes an commas

Answer (score 1):

With a regexp.
`num1.replace(/[^0-9.]/, '')`

Comment: You should also allow a minute sign for negative numbers.