# how reduce total sum , if at first I have a value of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In *string* is indented.

And when the sum is greater than *1000*, it is impossible to get *Total*.

**look at the picture please It will be more clear**

[image]

```
const Total = () => {
      const formValues = [
        {sum: '10', expenseType: ''},
        {sum: '1 000', expenseType: ''},
        {sum: '1 000', expenseType: ''},
        {sum: undefined, expenseType: ''},
      ] 
 

    const total = formValues.reduce((x, { sum }: { sum: number }) => Number(x) + Number(sum), 0);

  console.log(total)//NaN
  };
```

Comment: why the 1000 have space after the first number (1 000)?

Comment: Yes, but when the sum is greater than 1000 => total = NaN

Comment: Just remove the whitespace?

Comment: this is the designer's decision

Comment: I only want to remove when reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accommodating for the case where `sum` is `undefined` in your `reduce()` logic is pretty straightforward and can be done as follows:

```
const total = formValues.reduce((x, { sum }: { sum: number }) =>
    Number(x) + Number(sum || 0), 0);
```

However, that still leaves the problem of your number strings containing non-number characters. Borrowing the regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413943/3558960) to clean up the string:

```js
const Total = () => {
  const formValues = [
    {sum: '10', expenseType: ''},
    {sum: '1 000', expenseType: ''},
    {sum: '1 000', expenseType: ''},
    {sum: undefined, expenseType: ''},
  ];

  const total = formValues.reduce((x, { sum }) => 
    Number(x) + Number((sum || '').replace(/^(-)|[^0-9.,]+/g, '$1')), 0);

  console.log(total)//NaN
};

Total();
```

Comment: I think his problem is not that sum is undefined but sum has whitespaces and cannot be parsed to a number

Comment: @SirOneOfMany Thanks for pointing that out. Was too fast too post.

Comment: I think the first option is correct.

Comment: @АрамГаспарян `Number('1 000')` still evaluates to `NaN` though.

Comment: and how can I get back inside the total already ? 1 000 000 in this style

Comment: Cleanest way is to use a correctly configured [`NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
const total = formValues.reduce((x, { sum }: {sum: string}) => Number(sum) ? Number(x) + Number(sum) : Number(x), 0);
```